USB thumb copy fails without indication of error
Upon a review of my system wide data file backups, I discovered the contents on two of them mismatched the data being backed up.  No errors were reported.  A few files did have differences when compared with the originals.
To uncover this I used sha1sum to create check sums for the original and copies.  When a random few files showed a difference, I used diff to confirm it wasn't the same.  I then used cmp, which also confirmed it wasn't the same and, cmp provided an offset for the first difference.  Using hexedit I visually confirmed it wasn't the same.  Some times it was just a byte or two while others had larger differences.  One of the mismatched files was a zip file that I chose for a further test.  That zip file reported corruption when I attempted to open it further confirming it wasn't correct.
These files are copied to USB thumbdrives using
cp -r xxx .

within a shell script run from a command prompt. The current directory is the root of the thumbdrive.  No errors are reported to the terminal session running the command.
What technique might I use to improve the integrity of these backup shell scripts?
This is happening on 22.04 as well as 24.04.  The 32GB thumbdrives are formated ntfs.
